# manage.py migrate cannot access remote MySQL database

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, migrate

I have a Django app on that connects to a remote MySQL database (both on AWS, just different servers). The connection works fine and the app properly interacts with the database (fetches from and adds data to it).

However, when I am trying to perform a `manage.py migrate`, I get the following error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")`

Is there something specific to do for manage.py to interact with the remote database instead of trying to hit a local one (that doesn't exist)?

Comment: sounds like your running `manage.py` with different settings than when running the app. Something to do with local environment variables? Or different settings on your hosted server that you should tell `manage.py` about?

Answer (score 3):

You most likely have different settings on your hosted server than on your local machine. When you run `manage.py` on your hosted environment, you need to specify the settings file to use:

```sh
/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python manage.py migrate --settings=myapp.settings.production
```

or wherever your production settings are located. If you omit `--settings` you're running with the dev settings, like on your local machine.

Alternatively, you need to set the `$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable before running `manage.py migrate`

Comment: I have only one settings.py file. The app itself uses it to connect to the database without issue.

Comment: How do you develop on your local machine? the error shows the typical error you'd get if you're trying to connect to the local MySQL server. And what do you use to run the app (not `runserver` I hope)?

Comment: We're using uwsgi to run the app on the hosted server

Comment: and when running uwsgi, what's the `--env` setting?

Comment: Not sure because we are using an .ini file so we don't set the --env. But in the .ini we are setting the virtualenvironment to the correct directory

Comment: I don’t mean the virtualenv I mean the environment variables. Somewhere $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE must be defined.

Comment: Anyway try running your migrate command with the `—settings` flag